# Where does the Python class store arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

guys today I noticed something that about storage of python classes. I wanna show with an example.

```py
class foo:
    m = 19
    def __init__(self):
        self.z = 7
        self.y = 12
        self.p = 26
```

I was thinking till tomorrow that python saves all arguments in `__dict__` method. But when we call it:

```
ins = foo()
ins.__dict__
```

output:

```
{'z':7,'y':12,'p':26}
```

So now I was wondering, where has `m` gone? Why is it not including in this dict?

Comment: `inst.__dict__` is an *instance* level object and does not store class-level attributes such as `foo.m`

Comment: As `m` is a class variable rather than an instance variable, it's in the class itself - look at `foo.__dict__`.

Comment: c-nivs .I noticed it but, when we are instancing it , will created in instance object.But not showing in __dict__ unlike base of it foo...?...

Comment: Then I got it like that , When we are creating an object instance , it is also self.And then we calling self.__dict__.Due , only arguments which is created with self prefixed like "self." it will returned by the __dict__ yeah?That is right?

Answer (score 2):

Check the `foo.__dict__` :) .
The `m` in your case is a class attribute, not an instance attribute.

Check [this](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php) for more about that.

Comment: Yeah I dropped it to previous answer of me))Its work like this way i think.)